# I cannot loop in Fx.Move

Tags: javascript, mootools

I want to loop for ovject 'tablo' and move each position and loop to the next.
It is my source:

```
var tablo= {0:{x:5, y:12}, 1:{x:10, y:25}, 2:{x:7, y:22}, 3:{x:15, y:2},4:{x:13, y:30}};
var myfx;

function suite(num) {
    console.log(num);
    if (num < tablo.length) {
        pos = tablo[num];
        myfx.start({
           offset: pos,
            onComplete: function(){suite(num+1)}
        });
    }
}
pos = tablo[0];
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    myfx = new Fx.Move($('target'), {
        relativeTo: $('cartes'),
        position: 'upperLeft',
        offset: pos,
        duration: '1000',
        link: 'chain',
        onComplete: function() {suite(1);}
    }).start();        
});
```

console display  just 1.... and stop.
Where is the error?
Thanks

Comment: The value of `tablo` should be an array, not a plain object. Plain objects don't have a `.length` property.